# Cross-compile Linux-PAM: both pam.d and pam.conf are missing

Tags: linux, pam, powerpc

I am trying to cross-compile Linux-PAM from a Ubuntu host machine to powerpc architecture (running linux kernel 2.6.34). First, I run ./configure command, giving the --host path to the cross compiler and --prefix path to a local directory called "target" as options to the configure command; after that, I run make and make install. The make install command ends apparently without any error. At the end of the install process few files and directories are created in my "target" folder, but the /etc/pam.d is missing: I would have expected to find that folder, containing the PAM modules. A pam.conf file is missing too.
Am I doing something wrong? Or maybe the lack of both /etc/pam.d and pam.conf is an expected behavior?
these are the commands I tried to cross-compile:

```
export PATH=/path/to/crosscompiler/$PATH
./configure --prefix=/home/target --host=powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu
make
make install
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is expected behaviour as PAM was designed to be configured by a system administrator. In practice most Linux distributions will ship with their own default configuration and assumptions (c.f. Arch Linux: [pambase](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/any/pambase/), Debian: [libpam-runtime](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libpam-runtime)), so there is no canonical base configuration for PAM that each Linux system provides.

Looking at the source code there is an example [`conf/pam.conf`](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/conf/pam.conf) and you can convert it to a pam.d/ structure (e.g. by running `cat pam.conf | pam_conv1/pam_conv1` in the conf/ directory). There are also the instructions of the [Beyond Linux From Scratch manual](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/systemd/postlfs/linux-pam.html) which would result in a minimal setup.

However I would rather advise you to read the documentation (i.d. the man pages and the [System Administrators' Guide](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_SAG.html)) and depending on what you want to do maybe also distribution specific documentation (e.g. [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PAM), [Securing Debian Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/ch04s11.en.html)) so you know how PAM works and you can write the appropriate configuration.